# Let $g\in G$ and $H < G$. Suppose $g\in H$. Show that $\langle g\rangle \subset H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is what I tried but I'm a bit lost on what to do after:

Let $g\in G$ and $h\in H$

We know that $g \in H$. So, since $h \in H$, then we can say that $gh \in H$.

Comment: This follows from $H$ being closed under the group operation.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps start by writing down the definition of $<g>$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are important. First, what is the definition $\langle g\rangle$? It is the set
$\{g^n\mid n\in \Bbb Z\}$. Secondly, what means the subgroup generated by $g\in H$? It just means the smallest subgroup of $H$ containing $g$, and hence also all powers and the inverse and all powers. So
$$
\langle g\rangle =\{g^n\mid n\in \Bbb Z\}\subseteq H
$$
is the subgroup required.

Comment: It would be even easier if we think of $\langle g\rangle$ as "the smallest subgroup of that contains $g$"...

Answer (score 0):

What is the subgroup generated by an element $\langle g\rangle$? Write down the definition, your attempt shows there might be some confusion there.

Then observe that $H<G$, not merely $H\subset G$; so use the definition and closure of $H$ under the group operation to arrive at the result.